# How to set CompareToValue in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I'm trying to update a `<asp:CompareValidator Type="Currency">` dynamically. How can I set the value in the behind code?

Example:

- from.aspx

  ```
  <asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ID="vldCompare" Type="Currency" ErrorMessage="No!" />
  ```
- form.aspx.

  ```
  double value = 100.0;

  vldCompare.ValueToCompare = value.ToString() # !!! doens't work
  ```

When I do this, I get the message:

> System.Web.HttpException: The value '' of the ValueToCompare property
>   of 'vldAmount' cannot be converted to type 'Currency'.

Any hints on how to do this.

Comment: In your form.aspx, the `Type="Currency"`, do you have a specific class that is of type "Currency"?
Because the error you're receiving indicates that it's not receiving the exepcted type to use for comparison.

Comment: @SharpNip this is part of the ``CompareValidator`` syntax [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator?view=netframework-4.7.2](docs)